# How will HTML5 affect SEO for content and headings?

Tags: html, seo

Your opinion about HTML5 and longterm SEO.

Comment: Possibly an interesting question, but it's open-ended and subjective and not really a stackoverflow programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big thing for me is that if the content tags are used properly, "garbage" data will not be indexed - things like words appearing in Menus or other non related places will not be searched for.